# UIPageController content issue

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have a page controller with scroll view, a UIButton with target xib file and added as a subview to the scroll view, when I click on the first two pages the target action func called but when I click on the next pages it takes me back to the first page and the pages appears on top of each other:

```
func configureAddessesView(addresses: [User.Address]){
        addressPageController.numberOfPages = addresses.count
        let checkOutVC = CheckoutStory.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CheckOutVC2") as! CheckOutVC2
        for index in 0..<addresses.count {
            scrollViewFrame.origin.x = addressesView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            scrollViewFrame.size = addressesView.frame.size
            addressesView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            addressesView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddressView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AddressView
            view.frame = scrollViewFrame
            view.addressName.text = "\(addresses[index].name ?? String())"
            view.addressDetails.text = "\(addresses[index].city ?? String()),\(addresses[index].area ?? String()),\(addresses[index].street ?? String()),\(addresses[index].building ?? String())"
            view.addressPhoneNumber.text = "\(addresses[index].mobile ?? String())"
            view.tag = index
            view.addTarget(checkOutVC, action: #selector(checkOutVC.chooseNewAddress(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) //            view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printingg(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.addressesView.addSubview(view)
            self.addressPageController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
            //            let lbl = UILabel(frame: scrollViewFrame)
            //            lbl.text = "\(addresses[index].name ?? String())"
            //            lbl.textAlignment = .center
            //            self.addressesView.addSubview(lbl)
            //            addressName.text = "\(addresses[index].name ?? String())"
            //            addressDetails.text = "\(addresses[index].city ?? String()),\(addresses[index].area ?? String()),\(addresses[index].street ?? String()),\(addresses[index].building ?? String())"
            //            addressPhoneNumber.text = "\(addresses[index].mobile ?? String())"
        } //        let width1 = (Float(addresses.count) * Float(self.view.frame.size.width))
        addressesView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (addressesView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(addresses.count)), height: addressesView.frame.size.height)

    }
```

[that's what happen when I click on any page after the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvAoC.png)

Comment: Please make it a habit to add the proposed code as a code snippet instead of a screenshot.

Comment: thank you for the advice. @AhmadF

Comment: First, have you looked at using `UIPageViewController` to handle all of the sizing / positioning for you? Second, if you still want to manually add views to a scroll view, you'll be much better off using constraint-based auto-layout than calculating sizes.

Comment: @DonMag in my case it is complicated somehow because I'm putting the scrollview and pagecontrol in a stack view. in the end, I think the problem with the constraints of the scrollview but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @bahi.elfeky -- OK, then you need to show exactly what you are doing in order to get help resolving it. Might help if you review [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: ok, thank you @DonMag I appreciate that.